# styling css button on multiple file upload

Tags: css, file, button, upload, styling

There are many ways around to style the upload button. This is what I have, that works wonderfully if you wish to use one file upload:

```
<div class="file-upload">
  <div class="file-select">
    <div class="file-select-button" id="fileName">foto opladen</div>
    <div class="file-select-name" id="noFile">geen bestand gekozen</div>
    <input type="file" name="chooseFile" id="chooseFile">
  </div>
</div>
```

and css and js:

```
<script>
$('#chooseFile').bind('change', function () {
var filename = $("#chooseFile").val();
if (/^\s*$/.test(filename)) {
$(".file-upload").removeClass('active');
$("#noFile").text("No file chosen..."); 
}
else {
$(".file-upload").addClass('active');
$("#noFile").text(filename.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "")); 
}
});
</script>

<style>
.file-upload{display:block;text-align:center;}
.file-upload .file-select{display:block;color: #34495e;cursor:pointer;height:40px;line-height:40px;text-align:left;background:#fff;overflow:hidden;position:relative;}
.file-upload .file-select .file-select-button{background:#fff;padding:0 10px;display:inline-block;height:40px;line-height:40px;border:1px solid #6b8df2;border-radius: 20px;}
.file-upload .file-select .file-select-name{line-height:40px;display:inline-block;padding:0 10px;}
.file-upload .file-select:hover{border-color:#34495e;transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;}
.file-upload .file-select:hover .file-select-button{background:#6b8df2;color:#fff;transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;}
.file-upload.active .file-select{border-color:#6b8df2;transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;}
.file-upload.active .file-select .file-select-button{background:#6b8df2;color:#FFFFFF;transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-o-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;}
.file-upload .file-select input[type=file]{z-index:100;cursor:pointer;position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;top:0;left:0;opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);}
.file-upload .file-select.file-select-disabled{opacity:0.65;}
.file-upload .file-select.file-select-disabled:hover{cursor:default;display:block;border: 2px solid #dce4ec;color: #34495e;cursor:pointer;height:40px;line-height:40px;margin-top:5px;text-align:left;background:#FFFFFF;overflow:hidden;position:relative;}
.file-upload .file-select.file-select-disabled:hover .file-select-button{background:#dce4ec;color:#666666;padding:0 10px;display:inline-block;height:40px;line-height:40px;}
.file-upload .file-select.file-select-disabled:hover .file-select-name{line-height:40px;display:inline-block;padding:0 10px;}
</style>
```

But on my form I have eight pictures I need to be uploaded, so I need to style eight buttons [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwrDQ.jpg). I can't find the code to style the css when using multiple file upload buttons.

I also tried this, giving every input a different name=chooseFile, but won't work either:

```
<div class="file-upload">
  <div class="file-select">
    <div class="file-select-button" id="fileName">foto opladen</div>
    <div class="file-select-name" id="noFile">geen bestand gekozen</div>
     <input type="file" name="chooseFile1" id="chooseFile1">
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#chooseFile1').bind('change', function () {
var filename = $("#chooseFile1").val();
if (/^\s*$/.test(filename)) {
$(".file-upload").removeClass('active');
$("#noFile").text("No file chosen..."); 
}
else {
$(".file-upload").addClass('active');
$("#noFile").text(filename.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "")); 
}
});
$('#chooseFile2').bind('change', function () {
var filename = $("#chooseFile2").val();
if (/^\s*$/.test(filename)) {
$(".file-upload").removeClass('active');
$("#noFile").text("No file chosen..."); 
}
else {
$(".file-upload").addClass('active');
$("#noFile").text(filename.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "")); 
}
});
</script>
```

Can anyone help me out here, please? Thanks.

Comment: IDs need to be unique within the scope of an HTML document, so you can not just put the HTML snippet you have shown multiple times on your page as-is. This should first of all be re-written to not rely on IDs to select/find elements any more.

Comment: I changed the names like this:
<div class="file-upload">
  <div class="file-select">
    <div class="file-select-button" id="fileName">foto opladen</div>
    <div class="file-select-name" id="noFile">geen bestand gekozen</div>
    <input type="file" name="chooseFile1" id="chooseFile1">
  </div>
</div>
and adjusted the script, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question, and include the current state of your HTML and JS code, in comments this is hardly readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
<script>
$(".custom-upload").each(function() {
var uploadForm = $(this);
var uploadInput = $(this).find('#chooseFile');
$(uploadInput).bind('change', function () {
var filename = $(uploadInput).val();
if (/^\s*$/.test(filename)) {
$(uploadForm).find(".file-upload").removeClass('active');
 $(uploadForm).find("#noFile").text("No file chosen...");
}
else {
 $(uploadForm).find(".file-upload").addClass('active');
 $(uploadForm).find("#noFile").text(filename.replace("C:\\fakepath\\",     
""));
 }
});
});
</script>
```

and

```
<div class="custom-upload">
  <div class="file-upload">
    <div class="file-select">
      <div class="file-select-button" id="fileName">kies foto</div>
      <div class="file-select-name" id="noFile">geen foto gekozen</div>
      <input type="file" name="attach8" id="chooseFile">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Just change name (attach8) every new input.
Done!